# Date subtraction error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a few columns.

One of those columns is a `date` and another is `No of Nights`.

Number of nights is always a two character `varchar` column with values like 1N, 2N, 3N etc depending on the number of nights up to 7N.

I want to subtract the 1 part of the 1N column from the date.

For ex: **`25Oct15 - 1N = 24Oct15`**

Obviously I will be replacing the '1N' with the actual column name. I tried doing a trim as:

```
date - left(no of nights, 1)
```

But I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '25Oct16' to data type int.

Sample date below

```
Date                     |   NoofNIghts   | Result
 2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 |        1N      |
 2016-04-28 00:00:00.000 |        3N      |
```

Where the result column would be the subtracted value. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the 'N' in your data redundant considering the field is called NoofNights? Just sayin

Comment: And since **number** of nights sounds like a numerical value, it should be **stored as such** - in a `INT` column ....

Comment: Unfortunately this is a clients database i'm pulling data out of. Though i'm relatively new to sql i would have to agree with you in saying it should have been an int column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD ( DAY, - CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(NoofNights, 'N', '')), getdate() ) as Result
```

Comment: I marked this one as it gave me the easiest solution...Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @V_Date DATETIME = '2016-04-26 00:00:00.000'
        ,@V_NoofNIghts VARCHAR(2) = '1N'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, CAST(LEFT(@V_NoofNIghts,1) AS INT) *-1 ,@V_Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well basic query should be like

```
Update tablename
set result= DATEADD(d, -CAST(LEFT(NoofNIghts, LEN(NoofNIghts)-1) AS INT),Date)
```

Comment: You will need to explicitly convert to integer or it will complain about it. `Operand data type varchar is invalid for minus operator.`